# Bounds for Balls of $d_1,d_2,d_\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

> Recall that if $(S,d_s)$ and $(T,d_T)$ are metric spaces, then the functions
>
> $$\begin{align*}
> d_1(\mathbf x,\mathbf y)&=d_s(x_1,y_2)+d_T(x_2,y_2)\\[5pt]
> d_2(\mathbf x,\mathbf y)&=\sqrt{d_s(x_1,y_2)^2+d_T(x_2\color{red}{,}y_2)^2},\text{and}\\[5pt]
> d_\infty(\mathbf x,\mathbf y)&=\text{max}(d_s(x_1,y_2)+d_T(x_2,y_2))\\[5pt]
> \end{align*}$$
>
> are all metrics on $\color{red}{S \times T}.$
>
> Let $r \gt 0$ and $\mathbf x \in \color{red}{S \times T}.$
>
> Prove that there is some $s \gt 0$ so that $B^{d_1}_s(\mathbf x) \subseteq B^{d_2}_r(\mathbf x)$.

I'm not sure how to approach this. I tried framing it in the form $d_1(x,x+s) \Leftarrow d_2(x,x+r)$ but am getting nowhere with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $r>0$, pick $s > 0$ so that $s^2 = \frac{1}{2}r^2$, explicitly we define $s=\sqrt{\frac{r^2}{2}}$.

If then $\textbf{y} \in B^{d_1}_s(\textbf{x})$ we know that

$$d_S(x_1, y_1) \le d_1(\textbf{x},\textbf{y}) < s$$

and also

$$d_T(x_2, y_2) \le d_1(\textbf{x},\textbf{y}) < s$$

So that

$$d_S(x_1, y_1)^2 + d_T(x_2, y_2)^2 < 2s^2 = 2\cdot \frac{1}{2}r^2 = r^2$$

and it follows that

$$ d_2(\textbf{x}, \textbf{y}) < r $$

and so $\textbf{y} \in B^{d_2}_r(\textbf{x})$, as required.